# restrict space at first position in textbox using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to restrict users from entering space in beginning of a TextBox.
I am able to restrict space entry in TextBox. But not having any clues about not allowing at first position.

I am looking for a solution using JavaScript or jQuery. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just run a trim method on it. Clean it up when the user stops typing and clean it up on the server.

Comment: With jQuery there's a method for trimming white spaces: `$.trim('your.string')`

Comment: can someone share any link or snippet for same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event solution:

```
$("input").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32 && !this.value.length)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pdzBy/

Comment: Thanks vision.it almost does my job.just one more thing.can i also restrict space at the end of string??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar In this approach it is not effective, since you can't check which space is the very last while typing.

Comment: is there any other alternative that you can suggest?

Comment: Thanks, this is also a solution for me.

Comment: This might also be a solution for me if prevent spaces for following conditions as well.1. Enter text e.g. san diago 2. remove "san" and "diago" only 3. Now " " is only remain there and it allows to add. Please help me to par from this situtaions

Answer (score 2):

I tried but after writing something and moving the cursor to the first letter it allows a space there. This solution never allows entering a space character in the beginning of the text box.

```
$("input").on("keypress", function(e) {
    var startPos = e.currentTarget.selectionStart;
    if (e.which === 32 && startPos==0)
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can just call the trim method.

```
$.trim(' Hello World!'); // -> 'Hello World'
```

Note, this will remove all white space characters from the start and the end of your string.

Here is a demo using a button: http://jsfiddle.net/3Enr4/