# Simple PHP 'blog entry' form not submitting to MYSQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, blogs

I am trying to create a simple blog entry form where a user enters the title, blog entry and submits it. The form should then insert the 'blog entry' into MYSQL using the insert query.

- I am getting NO errors.
- When I submit form nothing is changed, the    database has no new
  entry and the form doesn't show "Post Submitted"    or "Post Not
  Submitted".

**Here is the blog.php code**

```
<?php 
    // 1. Establish a connection using three functions: 1. mysqli_connect() 2. mysqli_connect_errno() 3. mysqli_connect_error()
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "blog";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); 

    // Test if connection occured
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed " . mysqli_connect_error() . "( " . mysqli_connect_errno() . " )");
        }    

    //Form submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Error checking
    if(!$_POST['title']) {
        $error['title_error'] = "<p>Please supply a title.</p>\n";
        }

    if(!$_POST['blog']) {
        $error['blog_error'] = "<p>Please supply blog content.</p>\n";
        }

    //No errors, process
    if(!is_array($error)) {

    //Process your form
    // 2. Perform Your Query

    $post_title = $POST["title"];
    $post_content = $POST["blog"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO entries (blog_id, blog_title, blog_content) 
            VALUES ('null', '{$post_title}', '{$post_content}')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    //Display confirmation of post.

    if($result) {
        echo "Post submitted!";
        } else {
        echo "Error, post NOT submitted!";
    }

    //Require or include any page footer you might have
    //here as well so the style of your page isn't broken.
    //Then exit the script.
    exit;

    } else {
        echo $error;
        }
}

?>

<doctype>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Blog </title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="blog.php">
                Title: <input name="title"  type="text"> <br />
                Blog: <textarea name="blog" cols="100" rows="5"> Blog Text here... </textarea> <br />
                <input  value="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </body>

</html>
```

**Here is a screen shot of the form AFTER submitting it.**

[image]

**Here is a screenshot of MYSQL database called `blog`, and table called `entries`:**

[image]

**Here is the structure of my database:** 
[image]

**Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong. I am new to PHP and I have no idea how to debug a problem when I'm getting no errors!**

**UPDATE 1.** 
The solution worked. Thank you. However I getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\blogwebsite\blog.php on line 30

**I know it's because I have not initialized the $error[] array. But what is the standard way of getting rid of this error? Please help!**

Comment: It should be `$post_title = $_POST["title"]; $post_content = $_POST["blog"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` condition will not set as true because you did not set a name tag for your submit button.

It should be

```
<input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

Then on the re-assigning to another variable the passed-on data from the form, it should not be `$POST["title"]`, it should be `$_POST["title"]`.

You should also consider using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
$post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["title"]);
$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["blog"]);
```

But still, you should use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) rather than using `mysqli_*` with the functions of the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API.

Regarding the error you are getting for `undefined variable`, why don't you just scrap the input checking part of your code, and replace it with simply this:

```
if(!empty($_POST["title"]) || !empty($_POST["blog"])){ /* IF BOTH INPUTS HAVE CONTENTS */
  /* THE CODE YOU WANT TO EXECUTE */
}
else {
  $error = "<p>Please supply a title or a blog content.</p>\n";
}
```

Or just remove your input checking, and use HTML's `required` attribute.

```
<input name="title" type="text" required>
<textarea name="blog" cols="100" rows="5" required>
```

so that your PHP code will be straight-forward:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  /* YOUR INSERT QUERY HERE */  
}
```

The cons of `required`, as well as the `!empty()` condition, is that it accepts empty space (). To bypass this, you should use Javascript or libraries that support this kind of stuff.

Comment: The solution worked. Thank you. However I getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\blogwebsite\blog.php on line 30
 
**I know it's because I have not initialized the $error[] array. But what is the standard way of getting rid of this error? Please help!**

Comment: Thank you for your help! What is the standard way of working with errors in a form, and the most optimal way? Is it most popularly done through JavaScript out of the options you've listed?

Comment: Yes, javascript is the way to go for a thorough checking of forms. And BTW, if my answer did help you, you can upvote or accept my answer as the correct one.

Comment: @user3289740 You can post a new question or search for it, on how not to accept space. This is a good trick, [user can't use space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435036/restrict-space-at-first-position-in-textbox-using-jquery-javascript).

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should start learning JavaScript side by side with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In your html form, the submit element has two "value" attributes but no "name" attribute. Therefore it is not being found in the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) check and the original form being displayed as if nothing was posted.